# How to work around if/else statements in JSX?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

The following code obtains multiple queues with different stats and counts. For the last two counts (Billable Tickets Closed MTD and Billable Tickets Closed Last Month), I need to create an if/else statement because the counts are only available to some queues. I know JSX doesn't allow this, but what should I do moving forward?

```
const Results = () => {
    return (
      <>
        {
          results.map(i => (
              <ul>
                    <li
                      className={`colorDot && ${selectDashboard.name === i.u_dashboard && 'decreaseHeight'}`}
                      style={{ backgroundColor: determineDotColor(i.u_calls_in_queue) }}
                    ></li>
                    <li key={i.sys_id}><img src={logoMapper[i.u_dashboard]} alt="company logo"/><h1>{i.u_dashboard}</h1></li>
                    <li>Available Agents: <span className="callData">{i.u_agents_available}</span></li>
                    <li>Calls in Queue: <span className="callData">{i.u_calls_in_queue}</span></li>
                    <li>Longest Active Call: <span className="callData">{i.u_longest_active_call}</span></li>
                    <li>Longest Queued Call: <span className="callData">{i.u_longest_queued_call}</span></li>
                    <li>Queue Time Daily: <span className="callData">{i.u_queue_time_daily}</span></li>
                    <li>Queue Time MTD: <span className="callData">{i.u_queue_time_mtd}</span></li>
                    <li>Queue Time Last Month: <span className="callData">{i.u_queue_time_last_month}</span></li>
                    <li>Calls Taken MTD: <span className="callData">{i.u_calls_taken_mtd}</span></li>
                    <li>Calls Taken Last Month: <span className="callData">{i.u_calls_taken_last_month}</span></li>
                    <li>Billable Tickets Closed MTD: <span className="callData">{i.u_billable_tickets_closed_mtd}</span></li>
                    <li>Billable Tickets Closed Last Month: <span className="callData">{i.u_billable_tickets_closed_last_month}</span></li>
              </ul>
          ))
        }
      </>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those last two (which may or may not exist) you can just use an ternary:

```
{i.u_billable_tickets_closed_mtd && <li>Billable Tickets Closed MTD: <span className="callData">{i.u_billable_tickets_closed_mtd}</span></li>}
{i.u_billable_tickets_closed_last_month && <li>Billable Tickets Closed Last Month: <span className="callData">{i.u_billable_tickets_closed_last_month}</span></li>}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!